# How to display an svg image to img tag's onerror property with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have an image that display a jpg, but when there is an error, it shall display an svg image. However, Typescript claims onerror property only accept string. Is there a way to display an svg or a component instead with the onerror img property?

Here is my code:

```js
 <img
      width="100px"
      height="100px"
      src="myimg.jpg"
      onError={(e) => {(e.target as HTMLImageElement).src ="error.jpg"}}
    />

// And with the svg:

 <img
      width="100px"
      height="100px"
      src="myimg.jpg"
      onError={(e) => {(e.target as HTMLImageElement).src =<Icon src="error"/>}}
    />
```

I am using React + Typescript.

Comment: Could you share some of the code you're using?

Comment: Yes I typed too fast, it's now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You can import svg as `import svgImage from '../../mysvg.svg'`, this works as `src` of `img` tag. You can also import same svg as react component using `import {ReactComponent as SvgImage} from '../../mysvg.svg'` which can be mounted as `<SvgImage/>`. For your use case, you might want to import using first method.